# Android Facebook app - tabs

Tags: android, facebook, tabs, android-viewpager

I wonder which components Facebook is currently using for their tabs with icons + line.

Screenshot:

[image]

Currently I have a `ViewPager` and a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. But I wonder if they are using custom  components for the tabs or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ViewPagerIndicator` by *Jake Wharton* will give you a tabs, but it dosnt contain icons only tabs.

But you can use mine which is a fork from *Jake's* one, the lib come with a sample
[ViewPagerIndicator with Icon Only Tabs](https://github.com/JafarKhQ/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Comment: Thanks! What do I need to center my icons? currently there on the left of each tab item.

Comment: they should be centered, make sure you are using the correct style and check the icons

Comment: Ok, now this works. I also u this in my own lib project (fragment) but the tabs height is bigger, icons bigger too, what can be the problem? I'm using same icons like your sample.

Comment: Found it. png was in /drawable, when in xhdpi it's oké, I need to create multiple pngs (sizes). Thanks for your help.